# Can I transfer characters from one region to another in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I first installed Diablo 3, it defaulted the region to "The Americas" when I am Europe-based. I didn't notice until I played for a few hours. Is it possible to transfer my characters from one region to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found in this [thread](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4211011103), currently via their FAQ, **no you cannot perform a transfer.**